# gdb crashes!! -- QtLibrary4.8.4, QtCreator2.7.1 and MinGW 4.4,

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator, mingw32

I am using QtLibrary4.8.4(64 bit), QtCreator2.7.1(64 bit) and MinGW32 4.4.0 for Qt project development.
I can successfully run program but cannot debug it, on debugging the gdb crashes!!!
what can be possible reason. is it a version mismatch? Do I need to upgarde  or downgrade gdb??

N.B: I cant use the standalone SDK qt5.0 as I have to stick to version 4.8.4.

Thanks

Comment: Does it give any hint as to *why* it crashes?

Comment: Try to go to Qt Creator's options - Debugger - GDB and turn off all `stop when ... is called` checkboxes. It may help.

Comment: @cmannett85, no it doesnt . I just get a windows message that the gdb crashed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. When using QT you can't use the mingw gdb, instead use the compiled version from the QT-project site.

https://qt-project.org/wiki/QtCreatorBuildGdb